# Creating an inverted index of a numberic field in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, inverted-index

I have a dataset of about 20 million records, with the following structure:

```
{"id": "123",
 "cites":[
    {"id":"234", "date":"2018-05-04"},
    {"id":"456","date":"2018-02-01"}]
}
```

and I would like to make an index where I can see the list of the ids that cite an article, something like

```
{"id":"234", "cited_by":[{"id":"123"},{"id:"188"}]}
```

Which I understand is technically an inverted index. This can be static, so it could be computed just a single time. I've only seen documentation about inverted indices used for terms and their frequency in phrases, which is a very different use case.

I looked into using aggregations, but because the number of different ids is too large it runs out of buckets, and I am not sure 20 million buckets are possible and/or a good idea.

How could I generate this index? Is it possible in ElasticSearch, or would I need to write an external script that does this in batches?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

1. No problem to use ElasicSearch in your case.
2. Script to make the index

```
PUT /city_index
{
  "mappings": {
  "citydata": {
    "dynamic": "false",
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "keyword"

      },
      "cited_by": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, my question was more about how to populate the index with the data from the other index though!